# if $x = \sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{x+3}$ then x =?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have got a new question from my friend and it made me nervous:

$$\text{ If }\,x = \sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{x+3}, \text{ then }\,x = \;?$$

A lot of thank you to all comments.

Comment: Hint : Try repeated squaring

Comment: The solution is $10.675067392247516760$, as I found out with PARI/GP.

Comment: this equation can only be solved by a numerical method e.g. the Newton Method, it has exactly one solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are patient and follow Peter's suggestion of repeating squaring, you will end (if I did not make any mistake !) with $$x^8-12 x^7+6 x^6+92 x^5-31 x^4-248 x^3+192 x+64=0$$ which is not the nicest thing I ever saw. The original function looks much nicer and, as Dr. Sonnhard Graubner answered, only numerical methods will be able to find the root.

About repeated squaring, do not forget that this process generates extra roots. For the polynomial I wrote, the roots are $-0.817305$, $-0.415590$, $1.23610$, $1.95673$, $2.61688$, $10.6751$, $-1.62594 - 0.380736 i$,$-1.62594 + 0.380736 i$ while the original function has only one root.

Solving the original equation, you can easily show that the solution $x_{sol}$ is such that $$\frac{3}{2} \left(3+\sqrt{13}\right) \lt x_{sol} \lt \frac{3}{2} \left(3+\sqrt{21}\right)$$ the left bound corresponding to the solution of $x=3 \sqrt{x+1}$ and the right bound corresponding to the solution of $x=3 \sqrt{x+3}$. So, you could start iterations at $x=\frac{3}{2} \left(3+\sqrt{17}\right)$ corresponding to the solution of $x=3 \sqrt{x+2}$.

Performing a **single** iteration using Newton, you get $x=10.6750687237373$ which is not bad when compared to the almost exact value Peter gave.

**Added later**

In the post, you wrote that the problem from your friend made you nervous. Then, I give you one in order you play with his own nerves.

Ask him to find an approximate but accurate solution of the equation $$x=\sum_{i=1}^{100} \sqrt{x+i}$$ If you apply the method given above, the solution is such that $$100 \left(50+\sqrt{2501}\right)\lt x_{sol} \lt 1000 \left(5+\sqrt{26}\right)$$ the left bound corresponding to the solution of $x=100 \sqrt{x+1}$ and the right bound corresponding to the solution of $x=100 \sqrt{x+100}$. Taking the average of these bounds (they are very close to eachother $\approx 10000.1$ and $\approx 10099.0$), we could start iterating at $$x_0=50 \left(100+10 \sqrt{26}+\sqrt{2501}\right)\approx 10050.0$$ while the solution is $\approx 10050.2$.

You could easily show that, for a given large number $n$ of terms, the solution is approximately in the range $$n^2+1-\frac{1}{n^2}\lt x_{sol} \lt n^2+n+\frac{2}{n}$$ and that $$x_0=n^2+\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{n}$$ is a very good approximation of the solution (for $n=3$ as in your case, this gives an estimate equal to $\frac{65}{6}\approx 10.8333$ which is already quite good).

**Added later**

A further analysis shows that a very good estimate of the solution is given by $$x_{sol}\approx \frac{1}{2} \left(k^2+\sqrt{k^4+2 k^3+2 k^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

$$x=\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x+3}$$

$$x-\sqrt{x+1}=\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x+3}$$

$$x^2+x+1-2x\sqrt{x+1}=2x+5+2\sqrt{x^2+5x+6}$$

$$x^2-x-4=2(\sqrt{x^3+x^2}+\sqrt{x^2+5x+6})$$

$$x^4-2x^3-7x^2+8x+16=4(x^3+2x^2+5x+6+2\sqrt{x^5+6x^4+11x^3+6x^2})$$

$$x^4-6x^3-15x^2-12x-8=8\sqrt{x^5+6x^4+11x^3+6x^2}$$

$$x^8-12x^7+6x^6+156x^5+353x^4+456x^3+384x^2+192x+64=64x^5+384x^4+704x^3+384x^2$$

$$x^8-12x^7+6x^6+92x^5-31x^4-248x^3+192x+64=0$$

This equation has $6$ real roots, but only the one I mentioned in my comment fulfills the original equation. Therefore, it is the only real solution.

Comment: how did you find these roots?

Comment: With PARI/GP, a calculator.

Comment: oh fine in this case you could solve also the original equation

Comment: Yes, but I proved that there is only one, ans I calculated by hand as far as it was possible.

Comment: The galois group of the final polynomial is the full symmteric group, so the roots can be calculated only numerical. It is true that this could be done also for the original equation ...

Comment: @Peter: In the first place, even $\sqrt$ can only be calculated numerically, unless we like working in radical extensions. =)

Answer (score 4):

Since $x$ is the sum of three square roots, $x$ is positive. Thus there exists a positive real $y$ such that $x=y^2-2$.

The equation then becomes

$$y^2-2=\sqrt{y^2-1}+\sqrt{y^2}+\sqrt{y^2+1}$$

$$y^2-y-2=\sqrt{y^2-1}+\sqrt{y^2+1}$$

Squaring gives

$$y^4-2y^3-3y^2+4y+4=2y^2 + 2\sqrt{y^4-1}$$

$$y^4-2y^3-5y^2+4y+4=\sqrt{4y^4-4}$$

Squaring again

$$y^8-4 y^7-6 y^6+28 y^5+17 y^4-56 y^3-24 y^2+32 y+16=4y^4-4$$

$$y^8-4 y^7-6 y^6+28 y^5+13 y^4-56 y^3-24 y^2+32 y+20=0$$

This octic has [six real roots, of which five are extraneous](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E8-4+y%5E7-6+y%5E6%2B28+y%5E5%2B13+y%5E4-56+y%5E3-24+y%5E2%2B32+y%2B20%3D0). The approximate result is $$y \approx 3.56021$$

Using $x=y^2-2$ this gives $$x \approx 10.67507$$

Comment: What do you think strange is not strange. The truth is that every time you raise squared each algebraic expressions you enter one (1) new root in the equation. Example: $x=1\implies x^2=1\implies x=1 \mbox{or } x=-1$

Comment: @Elias: That's not true. Squaring in general will **double** the number of solutions, not add one more. In this case, squaring $3$ times resulted in $8$ solutions. However, squaring may even create an infinite number of solutions when there were originally none! For example square both sides of $|x-1|+|x+1|=-2|x|$.

Comment: @user21820 yes. I did not express myself properly. I wanted to say that for each root a new root is added. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: @Elias: Ah okay!

Answer (score 4):

Note that $x$ is positive, so we can write $x=y^2-2$, for some real number $y>\sqrt{2}$ and the equation becomes
$$y^2-2=\sqrt{y^2-1}+y+\sqrt{y^2+1}$$
we obtain thus 
$\sqrt{y^2+1}=y^2-y-2-\sqrt{y^2-1}$, hence
$$y^2+1=(y^2-y-2)^2+(y^2-1)-2(y^2-y-2)\sqrt{y^2-1}.$$
This yields
$$2(y^2-y-2)\sqrt{y^2-1}=(y^2-y-2)^2-2$$
so 
$4(y^2-y-2)^2(y^2-1)=((y^2-y-2)^2-2)^2$. Hence $y$ is a positive real root of the polynomial
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
P(y)&=&((y^2-y-2)^2-2)^2-4(y^2-y-2)^2(y^2-1)\\
&=&y^8-4y^7-6y^6+28y^5+13y^4-56y^3-24y^2+32y+20\end{array}$$
There is only one real root $y>\sqrt{2}$ of this polynomial.

Comment: We used the same substitution! +1

Comment: Yes, and at the same time. :-)